# Tensorflow restore error: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match

Tags: tensorflow

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [100,10] rhs shape= [300,10]
 [[Node: save/Assign_10 = Assign[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@label"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](label, save/RestoreV2_10)]]
 [[Node: save/RestoreV2_8/_9 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_26_save/RestoreV2_8", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

I train data using batch size is 300, while I restore and test model using batch size is 100. How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occours when you feed a tensor with a different shape from what was defined in the CNN model you trained. Since you said you first trained and then restored the model for testing, make sure the code you are using for restoring the model instantiates the same model you defined for training.

Comment: How can i define a model that i can using different batch size when i train and test model ? Most people say that inputing data using 'tf.placeholder()', while this is the only way to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried testing the trained model using the same tensor you used for training? Do this test to make sure the problem really is the different shape tensors.

Comment: Yes, if i use the same batch size, the code is no problem. and, finally i choose to use the 'tf.placeholder()', so there is no limit in batch size when train or test.